# Jmeter - Web page does not respond while changing recording controller

Tags: jmeter

Web page does not respond while changing recording controller.

I am trying to record a webpage and differentiate each page with a different recording controller.

However after recording the first page I change Target controller to a different recording controller so that I can differentiate each page separately.

After I change the target controller the webpage does not respond to any clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to do.

However, you have stop and then start the recording to make the proxy aware of any change.